# Eclipse Compiler Equivalent of -parameters

Tags: eclipse, reflection

I would like to use the Java Reflection API to obtain the names method parameters, using `java.lang.reflect.Parameter.getName()`.

I can achieve this for code that has been compiled using Sun's `javac` compiler, if I specify the `-parameters` flag, as seen here:

```
$> javac 
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
where possible options include:
  ...
  -parameters                Generate metadata for reflection on method parameters
  ...
```

However, I cannot find any matching option in eclipse that will add these names to the compiled byte-code.

Therefore, in Eclipse the parameter names are substituted with `arg0`, `arg1`, ...

The following illustrates the problem, stated output is from debug/run in Eclipse:

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] theseAreMyCliArgs) {
        // Ouptut [java.lang.String[] arg1]
        // Should yield [java.lang.String[] theseAreMyCliArgs]
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Example.class.getMethods()[0].getParameters()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about earlier versions, but Eclipse Luna (4.4) has that option in `Java->Compiler->Store information about method parameters`. It is only available for java 1.8 class file versions.

You can set it in project preferences to limit this additional metadata to selected project(s).

Comment: N.B. This is only available on javac 1.8 and above too.